# Pull variable from Javascript function (Phonegap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I tried to get value of variable from function beyond it, but always get error: Uncaught ReferenceError: devuuid_raw is not defined

The task is: I need to get value of variable beyond function in another variable because that value need to be used further (send to the server).

Code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log("Device is ready");
    var element = document.getElementById('devProps');
    devuuid_raw = device.uuid;
    return devuuid_raw;
    element.innerHTML = 'Идентификатор устройства: ' + device.uuid + '<br />';                                               
}

var devuuid = devuuid_raw;
```

How can I get device.uuid value outside the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a variable

```
var devuuid;
```

then add the event listener

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

and simply change the variable inside the function:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  console.log("Device is ready");
  var element = document.getElementById('devProps');
  devuuid_raw = device.uuid;
  devuuid = devuuid_raw;
  element.innerHTML = 'Идентификатор устройства: ' + device.uuid + '<br />';
}
```

If you don't use the 'var' keyword inside the function, it will reference to the variable defined before.

Comment: Thanks, your solution removed Uncaught ReferenceError, but I still cannot get value from variable, I tried this:

var devuuid;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

  function onDeviceReady() {
   console.log("Device is ready");
   devuuid = device.uuid;
   document.getElementById('devProps').value = devuuid;
  }

But variable still not show value :(

Comment: @user3166813 how and when do you check devuuid value?

Comment: <p id="devProps">Load info...</p> So, js code above should get element by id and show value, but it don`t do it, then I send this value with using jquery.ajax, but it also don`t work because it cannot get value

Comment: try `console.log(devuuid)` as last line inside the function. does it show the expected value? if you want to access the variable inside the javascript console, you have to create it globally without the 'var' keyword, e.g. `devuuid = 0;`

Comment: it don`t show the value, but I think it should not because device.uuid is specific phonegap feature and works only on phones

Comment: Correction: inside function log shows nothing, if place it outside it shows "undefined", if declare devuuid = 0; console log shows 0

Comment: also strange that I declared devuuid = 0; but <p id="devProps">Load info...</p> doesn`t show 0, because document.getElementById('devProps').value = devuuid; and devuuid = 0;

Comment: in element.innerHTML string you use `device.uuid`, not `devuuid`, that's probably why it won't show zero

Comment: @user3166813 if "devProps" is "p", why did you write "document.getElementById('devProps').value = devuuid;" instead of "document.getElementById('devProps').innerHTML = devuuid;"?